# Page not found while reload page during # removal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, nginx, gruntjs

I have made changes in my index.html and app.js.

> This is app.js file.

```
angular
        .module('assessmentApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'timer', 'assets', 'youtube-embed'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        /*$locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });*/
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
                $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                    enabled: true,
                    requireBase: true,
                    rewriteLinks: true
                });
            }
    }
```

> This is Index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assessment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/assessment/"></base>
</head>
</html>
```

1. I have followed all the solution which is present related to my problem but still my app not working.
2. **I am using nginx server but I don't know is any changes requied or not? If yes then what change?**
3. I added html5 api and base tag and i removed all # from my app html file so my app is working fine but when I am going to reload my application it return **page not found**

Comment: What does # have to do with your HTML file?

Comment: Before in my all html file had # with location like <a href="#/somelocation" class="alert-link">.But now i made change to <a href="somelocation" class="alert-link">. So working fine until i am not reloading page. So give me solution for when I will reload page it should not give page not found error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server is set so that it is returning your `index.html` instead of a 404.
In your nginx config for this site add:

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

Alternatively, you can redirect like this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I have used this and its working fine                                location /assessment/ {
       root /opt/www/;
       index index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /assessment/index.html?url=$uri;
    }

Comment: But I am getting page not found error when I used url give "grunt" example "http://myaddress/assessment-grunt/login/" but without grunt is working fine.So please tell me how does it work with grunt. I used in my "Gruntfile.js" inside the middleware "modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),"

Comment: Could you please give me the above comment answer.